# How to change the background color of the welcome screen of a pdf when we execute quickbuild in latex

Tags: texmaker, forward-inverse-search

The temporary pop up colour box highlighting the portion of text we edited in latex is set to red in the resulting pdf. Is there a way to change that temporary popup colour background to some other colour ? Of course it is not a permanent feature and lasts only a few seconds but it would be nice to have a way to customize this default feature.

Comment: Which editor do you use?

Comment: I am using Texmaker.